# Does SQL Server support the Oracle-like WITH clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, common-table-expression

I've seen mention of the Oracle WITH clause a few times around here for aliasing a subquery like this:

```
WITH myData AS (SELECT id, text FROM SomeTable)
SELECT myData from SomeOtherTable
```

Does any version of SQL Server support this?  If not, is there a particular reason they don't?  Performance?  Potential for incorrect usage?

Comment: BTW, note that this is not so much "Oracle-like" as "ANSI-SQL-like".

Comment: Really?  Would you happen to know where I can find a copy of the actual ANSI-SQL Standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 and up.

I wanted to add that you can stack these to good effect:

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT * FROM X
), B AS (
    SELECT * FROM A
), C AS (
    SELECT * FROM B
)
SELECT * FROM C
```

You can even do:

```
WITH A AS (
), B AS (
)
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON whatever
```

Also note that WITH must be the first keyword in a statement, so you often see it written as:

```
;WITH A AS (
)
```

Which basically terminates the previous statement (semicolons are kind of optional in T-SQL)

Answer (score 4):

Yes SQL2005 and SQL2008 both support this. They are called [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx).

Comment: ...and a lovely concept to bend your head with when trying to master the recursive CTE!

Comment: Yes, but actually the recursive CTE is not that bad once you've written a few.  It's way better than the alternatives (such as they are).